# MySQL error when using a column from a query in a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have the following code:

```
select count(*) as points
from question
where (select count(*) 
       from answer inner join answer_test
       on answer_test.id_r = answer.id_r 
           and answer_test.right = answer.right 
           and  question.id_i=answer.id_i ) = 4
```

I get this error:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'question.id_i' in 'on clause'
> How should I access **question.id_i** in the subquery without getting that error?

I need to calculate the grade from a test. Each question has 4 answer possibilities so you get a point if you have all right. 'Right' column is a boolean and question.id_i must match the answer.id_i but it says it does not recognize it even if it does exist. How should I modify it to make it work?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desird results.

Comment: You're putting  table 'question' in the join condition, but you're not asking to join it.

Comment: Give table `question` an alias and use it in that way in sub-query. (like this `from question q` and in join condition instead of `question` use `q`.

Comment: @farbiondriven I need that question.id_i from the outside query, that's why I didnt specify it there. It must match the outside one

Comment: @michal.jakubeczy unfortunately it is still the same.. I get the error with q.id_i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but put your condition with `question` table in `where` clause as follows:

```
select count(*) as points
from question
where (select count(*) 
       from answer inner join answer_test
       on answer_test.id_r = answer.id_r 
           and answer_test.right = answer.right 
           Where question.id_i=answer.id_i ) = 4 -- condition in where
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as points
from question as q
where (select count(*) 
       from answer inner join answer_test
       on answer_test.id_r = answer.id_r 
           and answer_test.right = answer.right 
           and  q.id_i=answer.id_i ) = 4
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.